# Performance impact of SQL database in VirtualBox VM on SBS2011 vs hosting that database directly on SBS

Tags: windows, sql, virtualbox

one of our customers still has a somewhat functioning SBS2011. That SBS also hosts the files and database (some MS SQL Express) for the customers primary application. 
The server also hosts an anti-virus management server, but this one actually runs in a Windows 7 VM in VirtualBox - on that SBS2011 box. The reason being that both the customers primary application and the anti-virus management server actually @default use the same SQL ports. So that's the workaround.

That VM however has shown some reliability issues lately, as in not automatically booting up when the SBS has its patch tuesday (or a colleage forgetting to turn on the VM) or the actual service for the anti-virus management not starting or just plain going off for some reasonidontknow...

So my plan is to install the management server directly on the SBS and modifying the connection ports in the AV software which is fully supported, so that the SQL instances of the primary application and AV management do not interfere.

However, we have a lively discussion whether it wouldn't be preferrable to rebuild the VM/fix it instead of putting it onto the SBS.

My argument: VirtualBox (or any type-2-hypervisor) is inherently unreliable (qed) for such an important task, puts unnecessary overhead on the SBS for no real gain and creates another layer of unnecessary complexity. We would free up more ressources by installing the AV management (and its db) directly on the SBS.

Colleagues argument: The SBS2011 already has "enough" databases/instances (sbsmonitoring, exchange, the primary application db, sharepoint etc.), so that an additional database might actually do more harm because now the SBS has to "manage" another SQL database and its ressources instead of a VM with fixed ressources.
Counterargument: We have a few more customers with comparable systems where my structure doesn't pose a problem.

So, what would your recommendation be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without getting into any of the vagaries and nuances; no reasonable person would use VirtualBox for production workloads and critical line of business applications. I'm in agreement with you in regards to ditching VirtualBox.

Comment: VirtualBox is hardly designed or intended for the scenario you've described here. It's _at best_ desktop virtualization for end users. It works poorly for any other purpose.